# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools

Tags: software-installation, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I started an upgrade of my Kubuntu 12.04 system with this command, as usual:

```
sudo apt-get --show-upgraded dist-upgrade
```

I came back later and it had failed:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 478306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace  ...
Unpacking replacement base-files ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-lowlatency

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-lowlatency with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

here's the problem:
$ df -h output:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                     894M  879M     0 100% /boot
```

manually deleted older files and now some space is free

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                     894M  129M  717M  16% /boot
```

I ran this next:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Next:

`sudo apt-get -f install` output:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.3.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.4.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools`
the above fails

`dpkg -l initramfs-tools` output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
iF  initramfs-tool 0.99ubuntu13.3 tools for generating an initramfs
```

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools` output:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.3.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.4.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools`:

```
initramfs-tools-bin:
  Installed: 0.99ubuntu13.4
  Candidate: 0.99ubuntu13.4
  Version table:
 *** 0.99ubuntu13.4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.99ubuntu13 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
initramfs-tools:
  Installed: 0.99ubuntu13.3
  Candidate: 0.99ubuntu13.4
  Version table:
     0.99ubuntu13.4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.99ubuntu13.3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.99ubuntu13 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

As suggested below, here are my next steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -f install initramfs-tools=0.99ubuntu13 initramfs-tools-bin=0.99ubuntu13

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ...
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 59.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main initramfs-tools all 0.99ubuntu13 [49.2 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.99ubuntu13 [9,988 B]
Fetched 59.2 kB in 0s (124 kB/s)            
dpkg: warning: downgrading initramfs-tools-bin from 0.99ubuntu13.4 to 0.99ubuntu13.
(Reading database ... 478624 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace initramfs-tools-bin 0.99ubuntu13.4 (using .../initramfs-tools-bin_0.99ubuntu13_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement initramfs-tools-bin ...
Setting up initramfs-tools-bin (0.99ubuntu13) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.99ubuntu13.3); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Next I tried Giles's suggestion:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Please post the output of `apt-cache policy initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools`

Comment: @Gilles - thanks for looking at it. I updated the question with this info.

Comment: Try manually specifying the version: `apt-get install initramfs-tools=0.99ubuntu13.4`

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like a bug in either the dependencies of the `initramfs-tools` package or in how dpkg manages them. I think your system isn't supposed to get in this state where the new `initramfs-tools-bin` is marked as installed but the old `initramfs-tools` is still there. Does `dpkg --configure -a --force-depends` help?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `dpkg --audit`?

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a --force-depend` solved it!!! Thanks Giles!

Comment: @MountainX I recommend you to do `dpkg --audit` before announcing victory. His suggestion only force dpkg to install the stuff, it may cause problems in the long term.

Comment: @Braiam Isn't `apt-get -f install` sufficient? What more does `dpkg -C` do here?

Comment: @Braiam I ran `sudo dpkg --audit`. It returns to the command prompt with no output. And I did a dist-upgrade after doing what Giles suggested and it worked fine.

Comment: @Gilles dpkg was the one trowing dependencies issues rather than APT, to APT everything was a-ok (actually I can't put my finger on what wicked behavior is this as debian doesn't use the -bin package). I checked out [the package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/initramfs-tools) and that added more confusion. `initramfs-tools` version `0.99ubuntu13.3` depends of any `initramfs-toos-bin` between `0.99ubuntu13.3` and `0.99ubuntu13.3.1~` but doesn't allow installing when both packages are the same version.

Comment: searching around a little it seems that if `dpkg --audit` simply returns to the command line, everything is good.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your system is in a state which I think should not happen: you have the new version of the dependency `initramfs-tools-bin` in the installed state, but the old version of the dependency `initramfs-tools` in a half-installed state. I'm not sure whether the problem is that APT is letting the system get into a state where it can't recover, dpkg is letting the system get into a state where it can't recover, the package maintainer used a combination of dependencies which isn't supported, or my limited understanding doesn't cover this case.

Try using `dpkg` directly:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

If this still complains about dependencies, try

```
dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```

If this works, you have the dpkg database in a consistent state. You need to get APT in a good state (which requires no broken dependencies):

```
apt-get -f install
```

After this you can resume normal upgrading.

---

If your purge of `/boot` was deleting old kernels that were in packages, you won't be able to remove the kernel packages anymore. You'll have to recreate the files. You can create empty files (`` touch `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-1.2.3-foo` ``) if you're removing the `linux-image-1.2.3-foo` package and you manually removed some of its files.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! dpkg with --force-depends makes the difference and then fixing the broken package did the trick

Answer (score 3):

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-lowlatency

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

This means that you need to remove some kernels. Old, unused kernels are the best alternative.

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-generic-someold-version
```

> **manually deleted** older files and now some space is free

## NO!

You should never manually remove anything. Ever. Only stuff from `/home` and `/tmp` that may be easily recoverable can me touched by hand, otherwise use the tools. That's the point of having DPKG/APT to your service. If you need to remove something use apt/dpkg instead and leave stuff done by hand as last alternative. I'm presuming your current problem is because of this.

---

To solve the dependency issue, you may downgrade, then upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install initramfs-tools=0.99ubuntu13 initramfs-tools-bin=0.99ubuntu13
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

By this point you should have told dpkg/apt to remove the old kernels too.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It also fails. I updated my question with the output.